# How to display string with HHmm format

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, datetime-format

I have string value 17:00:25

how do i display in Military time like 1700 only?
im debugging it with like below

```
Dim time As String = String.Format("{0:hh:mm}", row("timereported"))
MessageBox.Show(time.ToString)
```

and the actual code is

```
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
     rowInsert = DS.Tables(0).NewRow
     Dim time As String = String.Format("{0:hh:mm}", row("timereported"))
     rowInsert(0) = time
     DS.Tables(0).Rows.Add(rowInsert)
Next row
```

but it display as 17:00:25

any other kinds of conversion or format suited to format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is a TimeSpan...

```
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
  rowInsert = DS.Tables(0).NewRow
  Dim time As String = Format(New Date + CType(row("timereported"), TimeSpan), "HHmm") 'this line changed'
  rowInsert(0) = time
  DS.Tables(0).Rows.Add(rowInsert)
Next row
```

If the column is a string...

```
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
  rowInsert = DS.Tables(0).NewRow
  'new code starts'
  Dim time As String = ""
  Dim tsp As TimeSpan
  If TimeSpan.TryParse(CStr(row("timereported")), tsp) Then
    time = (New Date + tsp).ToString("HHmm")
  End If
  'new code ends'
  rowInsert(0) = time
  DS.Tables(0).Rows.Add(rowInsert)
Next row
```

Comment: the 17:00:25 is mySQL time data type sir

Comment: I've changed the code to treat the field as a TimeSpan, let me know if it works.

Comment: I've also added code for if the field is a text field

Answer (score 0):

```
Const militaryTimeFormat As String = "HHmm"

' convert to a string in military time
Dim input As String = DateTime.Now.ToString(militaryTimeFormat)
MsgBox(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the strongly typed [`Field` method of the datarow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the value as a TimeSpan (you mentioned that it is stored as a Time data type in mySQL so this is the correct .NET equivalent)

Then you can format the timespan. Note the [Timespan formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are different from DateTime formats:

```
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    rowInsert = DS.Tables(0).NewRow
    Dim time As String = row.Field(Of TimeSpan)("timereported").ToString("hhmm")
    rowInsert(0) = time
    DS.Tables(0).Rows.Add(rowInsert)
Next row
```

For reference this:

```
Dim ts As New TimeSpan(17, 0, 25)
Debug.WriteLine(ts.ToString("hhmm"))
```

Outputs

```
1700
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't attempt to format a string value to get a *datetime* value, otherwise you're denying yourself access to .net's inherent *datetime* handling features.

A safer way to handle the *datetime* value would be the following...

- If returning data from your database, return as a *datetime*, or *datetimeoffset* value.
- If it is a user entry and you are handling a string (which is the only scenario I can think of that would warrant this), then validate and cast to a *datetime* value.

The value should be of *datetime* ***before*** you attempt to format it.

This would leave you with a clean way to handle this using the format code "t" where you place your parameter, and no issues with invalid values.

Importantly it also makes your code culture safe if your site is multilingual. For example *en-GB* would display "17:00" while *en-US* would display "5:00pm".

So for your code it would then simply be...

```
Dim time As String = String.Format("{0:t}", row("timereported"))
```

This would give you the format "HH:mm" or for your example "17:00".